# Removing '/store/' Default Slug from Custom Vendor URL Creation

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Have you successfully removed the /store/ default slug on a Woocommerce Wordpress site?

I'm building a multi-vendor site right now and every store page has url of:

```
domain.com/store/vendor-name
```

I, and customers, strongly prefer this format, removing the '/store' slug entirely.

```
domain.com/vendor-name
```

It looks like this is set by Wordpress by default. I'm using the Dokan plugin but can't seem to find where this URL is created. Any help would be greatly appreciated! I've seen plugins that eliminate the '/category/' or '/product' slugs but nothing for /store/. I'd be happy to manually edit something if need be, but a plugin would be great if possible.

Comment: have you tried checking `Settings > Permalinks`?

Comment: I have, but inside the Wordpress UI it doesn't let you change the permalinks on /store/. Also, they don't allow (or recommend) removing the slugs. This is more common for /product/ and /product-category/